# Is this a JavaScript counter?

Tags: javascript, counter

I've seen this pattern all over the place, but I'm not sure what it does:

```
x.memb = x.memb ? x.memb + 1 : 1;
```

I think it's a counter but I'm not so sure. Can someone explain what this does and the logic?

Comment: "ternary operator" google it.

Comment: If `x.memb` returns `true` , increment it else set it to 1.

Comment: its just a syntactic sugar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

Answer (score 3):

If `x.memb` is already defined and isn't `0`, then it increments it. In other cases, it sets its value to `1`.

It's basically just an increment taking care of the case where `x.memb` isn't defined.

You could also have written it as

```
x.memb = (x.memb||0) +1;
```

which might be more idiomatic as `value||defaultValue` is an usual construct in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

this is a ternary operatior doing some counting.

in essence it's doing this

```
if(x.memb)
   x.memb = xmemb + 1; //increment it
else
   xmemb = 1; //start it off
```

It's just shorthand. If the thing before the `?` is true it will return whatever is before the `:` if it's false it will return whatever is after the `:`

Note that this is a very handy mechanism for all sorts of forks that have nothing to do with counting. It's just being used that way in this situation.